# What is the Core Foundation equivalent code for the Cocoa method +[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:]?

Tags: core-foundation

I'm using Core Foundation functions. What is the Core Foundation equivalent code for the Cocoa expression `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]`?

Answer (score 2):

Create a CFURL referring to the file and [ask it for the data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLAccessUtils/Reference/reference.html).